# SQL: Selecting User IDs, and excluding all the User IDs if one entry has a certain value

Tags: sql, select

[image: My database]

Hi,

Looking at the picture I've attached. I'm trying to select all the User IDs which do not have a Role ID of 1. So I want the query to return User IDs 6, 13, and 15. However, when I use a query for this it will also return User ID 5, as it has 2 entries, with one entry having a Role ID of 3. Is there anyway to exclude UserID 5 due to its associaiton with having a RoleID of 1?

```
SELECT UserID
FROM UserTable (example)
WHERE RoleID <> 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use not exists

```
select t.UserID from UserTable  t
where not exists ( select 1 from UserTable t1 
                   where t1.Userid=t.userid and Roleid=1
                  )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT UserID
FROM UserTable (example)
WHERE UserID not in (SELECT UserID FROM UserTable (example) WHERE RoleID = 1)
```

First of all we select all the users with RoleID = 1 and we select their userIDs, and then we select all the users that are not in the first list.

Comment: the `DISTINCT` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

If you only want `userId`s, then use `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT UserID
FROM UserTable 
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN RoleID = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

This selects each (appropriate) `UserId` *once* -- which seems to be what you are asking for.

The `HAVING` clause is counting the number of roles that are "1".  The `= 0` says that there none exist.